# Table Referencing with VS Code

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm pretty new to LaTeX document, and having a problem with table referencing. Previously I compiled and built in Atom.io editor and recently switched to VS Code. It did work previously, but now it makes reference error with table!

The console keeps saying

> Reference 'tab:table1' on Page 2 undefined.

I don't understand why this worked previously and now it doesn't?

It shows `???` for `\ref` value.

Below is a minimal code for this problem's reproduction. I used `IEEEtran` template for my document.

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

See \ref{tab:table1}\.

\begin{table}[ht] {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} \hline
    \bf Task & \bf Assignee & \bf \multicolumn{1}{l}{Description} \\ \hline
    Project Manager & Alice & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.3cm}|}{\raggedright Schedule overall development plan and assign proper jobs to team members} \\ \hline
    Consumer & Bob & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.3cm}|}{\raggedright Test and try out a prototype application, gather the potential improvement} \\ \hline
    User & Chris & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.3cm}|}{\raggedright Gather basic feature requirement for this project by asking qeustioaires the eldery near the university.} \\ \hline
    Developer & Daniel & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.3cm}|}{\raggedright Prepare a development environment for this project and build up the application} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}} \\
    \caption{Task distribution  for each participants of this project}
    \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile the document at least two times to have the references correct. You code worked like a charm on Overleaf.

However, I suggest that you load the package [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), which will help you get much better references. I also load the package [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).

I have also cleaned up you code, changes the depreciated command `\bf`\ to `\bfseries` and changed the third column to a `p`-column. In addition, you had defined four columns, but only used three. Consequently, I removed the fourth column.

I have also included an example 2 where I use [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to have a much nicer tabular without any vertical lines. Unless it is a requirement of your publisher, I would have moved the caption above the table and used the package [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to format it. In addition, I suggest using [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), to line up the caption and the tabular correctly at the right margin of the  tabular (in addition, [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) handles table notes correctly).

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cleveref, array}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

See \cref{tab:table1}.

\begin{table}[ht] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm}|}
    \hline
    \bfseries Task & \bfseries Assignee & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries Description} \\
    \hline
    Project Manager & Alice & Schedule overall development plan and assign proper jobs to team members \\
    \hline
    Consumer & Daniel & Test and try out a prototype application, gather the potential improvement \\
    \hline
    User & Bob & Gather basic feature requirement for this project by asking questionnaires the elderly near the university. \\
    \hline
    Developer & Chris & Prepare a development environment for this project and build up the application \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} \\
    \caption{Task distribution  for each participants of this project%
    \label{tab:table1}}  %% Label inside caption
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption), [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable)**
[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cleveref, array, booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelsep=period, font={footnotesize, sc}]{caption}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

See \cref{tab:table1}.

\begin{table}[ht!] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}

\begin{threeparttable}

    \caption{Task distribution  for each participants of this project%
    \label{tab:table1}}    %% Caption above tabular, label inside caption
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Task & \bfseries Assignee & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Description} \\
    \midrule
    Project Manager & Alice & Schedule overall development plan and assign proper jobs to team members \\ 
    Consumer & Bob & Test and try out a prototype application, gather the potential improvement \\ 
    User & Chris & Gather basic feature requirement for this project by asking questionnaires the elderly near the university. \\ 
    Developer & Daniel & Prepare a development environment for this project and build up the application \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, but would you edit the part including all personal info? I accidentally did not modify that part and your solution codes all have some poeple's names... You can refer to my editted codes on question. Sorry for inconveniences.

Comment: @cadenzah Done. If my answer was to any help, I appreciate if you accept it :)

Comment: Great, thank you!